# How to proceed to logout page by using logout button in php

Tags: php

```
<form action="logout.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
```

This is my code. Why i can't proceed to logout.php when i clicked on Logout button? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: No, there isnt. Is the `form`-Tag closed?

Comment: Why you need a `form` for this? You are not submitting/passing any values, You can do it using a link.

Comment: Is this your complete form code???

Comment: Working fine even without the closing form tag http://jsfiddle.net/L9YL9/  Not sure what you mean by `I can't proceed to logout.php`

Comment: And are you sure you 've placed "logout.php" in same directory as that of your file containing this code???

Comment: @asprin oh yes, i forgot about the "advantages" of HTML.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Wasn't implying that there shouldn't be a closing form tag. The intention was to show that the `action` will take place even if there is no closing tag. So you can skip the sarcasm here

Comment: yes...i closed the tag already....i can't access to logout.php although i clicked on logout button and placed logout.php in same directory

Comment: @user3680780: Do you've any js code associated with submit button in your file???

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use link instead.

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a button that goes to a link. You can also just make an anchor and then just style it in CSS to look like a button. With that, you don't need any forms.

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

As for it not working, the logout.php is maybe missing. When you say you can't proceed to the logout, what exactly is the problem. Do you leave the page where the button is?